# How to differentiate falsey array values from falsey out-of-bounds indices in php?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

In what ways can one determine whether the value of an array's index is falsey due to an out-of-bounds index in PHP?

For example, one might erroneously conclude that both `$a` and `$b` below have at least three items each, since the comparison of the third items in both arrays purport to have identical values at index `2`, when in reality there is no index `2` in array `$b`. Indeed both values are `null`.

```
$a = array(1, false, null, 1, 0);  
$b = array(true, 0);

echo (int)($a[0] === $b[0]); // 0  
echo (int)($a[1] === $b[1]); // 0  
echo (int)($a[2] === $b[2]); // 1  null<declared>===null<index-out-of-bounds>
echo (int)($a[3] === $b[3]); // 0  
echo (int)($a[4] === $b[4]); // 0
```

Comment: if done in a loop (or outside I guess too) I would just check that each key exists in each array using [array_key_exists](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question... Maybe somthing like this (but only for numeric array indexes):

```
(int)(count($a)>=$i && count($b)>=$i && $a[$i]===$b[$i])
```

?

EDIT: probably better solution based on array_key_exists:

```
(int)(array_key_exists($i, $a) && array_key_exists($i, $b) && $a[$i]===$b[$i] )
```

Comment: Er... I think `isset($a[$i])` is preferable to any of this `count()` business.

Comment: was my first thought too... but "isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL", see http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php . So isset returns false on nul value as well as on unexisting variable (or out of bounds in the OP). Gives no help...